# Non System.Web alternative to HttpContext.Current

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, thread-safety

I'm working on a legacy ASP.NET Web API 2 project that is polluted with usages of `HttpContext.Current`. I'm trying to move the application to OWIN (ASP.NET Core is not an option at this stage) to utilize `Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer`, where `HttpContext.Current` will not work because it's tightly coupled with IIS through System.Web assembly.

So I'm trying to implement an alternative using `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` (I realize this is a different type but I believe I can refactor my way out of it). The basic idea is to add a `System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler` to Web API which will intercept the incoming request and assign it to a static property. This property will replace usages of `HttpContext.Current`. Now, before you propose using the `ApiController.Request` property - the static field is used deep in a dependency graph, so passing it as parameter all the way from the controller would be difficult if not impossible.

Because there are multiple requests handled in parallel, a simple static property with implicit field would not work. It would get overwritten constantly by different threads handling the requests. I could use a `ThreadStaticAttribute` but there's still a risk with `async` - if a request is handled by multiple threads, my field could end up being null (or worse yet, another request).

## Original question

To mitigate this, I'm thinking of binding each request to `SynchronizationContext.Current` in a dictionary which will back the static property. Something like this:

```
class CurrentRequestProvider
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<SynchronizationContext, HttpRequestMessage> Requests =
      new ConcurrentDictionary<SynchronizationContext, HttpRequestMessage>();

    static HttpRequestMessage CurrentRequest
    {
      get
      {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current is object &&
            Requests.TryGetValue(SynchronizationContext.Current, out var request))
        {
          return request;
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
}
```

Then the `DelegatingHandler` is nested in `CurrentRequestProvider`, so it has access to the `Requests` dictionary:

```
class SetCurrentRequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            Requests.AddOrUpdate(SynchronizationContext.Current, request, (sc, r) => request);
            /* Execute controller's actions and everything */
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        finally
        {
            /* Clean up the dictionary of requests */
            Requests.TryRemove(SynchronizationContext.Current, out _);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, onto my question to multi-threading gurus :). Is it enough to use `ConcurrentDictionary` as I did to ensure thread safety in this scenario, or should I add some extra locking in `CurrentRequest`'s getter or somewhere else? Do you spot any other potential problems with this workaround?

Thanks in advance.

## Update with solution

acelent's comment below directed me to a better approach based on `AsyncLocal<T>`:

```
class CurrentRequestProvider
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<HttpRequestMessage> AsyncLocalRequest =
      new AsyncLocal<HttpRequestMessage>();

    static HttpRequestMessage CurrentRequest => AsyncLocalRequest.Value;

    class SetCurrentRequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                AsyncLocalRequest.Value = request;
                /* Execute controller's actions and everything */
                return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
            finally
            {
                AsyncLocalRequest.Value = null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see the need to provide extra thread-safety anymore with this approach (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Take a look at [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1).

Comment: @acelent Great! I didn't know that one, thanks. I'll update the question.